# Display JSON object as string using Express

Tags: json, mongodb, express

I am using Express and MongoDB for my project. I am displaying database fields. All good except for a field that is a JSON object.

here is how that field is stored:

```
    "Color" : {
        "0" : "Green",
        "1" : "Blue"
    },
```

I am looping through the rows and here is how I am displaying the fields:

```
                                <% if (site[field.fieldname]) { %> 
                                    <div class="row mb-2 mt-2">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                                <h6><%= field.fieldname %> </h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6">
                                                <%= JSON.stringify(site[field.fieldname]) %>
                                                <!-- <%= site[field.fieldname] %> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                                    
                                <% } %>
```

This is how it displays currently.

{"0":"Green","1":"Blue"}

Instead I want it to display just this: Green, Blue

How can I achieve that?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you try to do Object.values(Color) in order to extract all values into an array ?

Comment: You say it's already json. Why `JSON.stringify` then?

Comment: No. I just tried using JSON.stringify. I am trying to see how I can parse the values individually and display as strings

Comment: I finally got what you meant Srinivasy. I did <%= Object.values(site[field.fieldname]) %> and it works fine now.